# How to make responsive image in exact center of screen and equal margins on all sides?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Does anyone know how to do this? I've been trying for a while but can't get it to work on the bottom margin. This fashion(?) site demonstrates what I mean though:
http://vyctoire.com/

It's responsive so that at all times (until mobile sizes), the margins are all equal. Do you know a way to do this using html and css? Or even with jquery too.

Comment: Please post some code? which you have tried?

Answer (score 1):

Flexbox has `align-items: center;` and `justify-content: center;` I wouldn't ever suggesting using it like I have in my snippet, it's just an example to show you what it looks like.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: 0;
}

.faux-image {
  width: 25vw;
  height: 25vh;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="faux-image"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

On vyctoire.com website, they use absolute positioning. Using CSS, you can do something like this:

```
.container {
  position: absolute;
  left: 100px;
  top: 100px;
  right: 100px;
  bottom: 100px;
}
/* Supposing the wrapper around #container is 100% wide and high */
```

Or:

```
.container {
  left: 100px;
  top:  100px;
  width: calc(100vw - 200px);
  height:  calc(100vh - 200px);
}
```

Comment: Really simple and it worked. Thanks a lot. One problem I'm curious if you know how to fix. I'm adding a section below the fold so if you scroll down you'll see some other content. Problem is, when I add a section below the fold, the scrollbar appears which is fine. But the viewport width and height dont change, so the everything looks shifted to the left, any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

**html code**

```
<div id="slider">
 <figure>
 <img src="images/16711537_10208952366430422_5249357485128837134_n.jpg" alt>
  img src="images/images (1).jpg" alt>
 <img src="images/images (2).jpg" alt>
  <img src="images/images.jpg" alt>


</figure>
</div>
```

> set your images path for this img src

**css**

```
@keyframes slidy {
   0% { left: 0%; }
  20% { left: 0%; }
   25% { left: -100%; }
  45% { left: -100%; }
50% { left: -200%; }
70% { left: -200%; }
 75% { left: -300%; }
95% { left: -300%; }
100% { left: -400%; }
 }

  body { margin: 0; } 
  div#slider { overflow: hidden; }
  div#slider figure img { width: 20%; float: left; }
  div#slider figure { 
   position: relative;
   width: 500%;
  margin: 0;
   left: 0;
   text-align: left;
    font-size: 0;
   animation: 30s slidy infinite; 
   }
```

Comment: I don't think this really answers the question

Comment: I think to he wants to the responsive side show.so I proposed that solution.

Comment: I think he wants to centre an image vertically and horizontally "image in exact center of screen" - OP 

Comment: Oh, also people respond to snippets better than just raw code which is why I edited it. I didn't actually change your code (other than fix your broken syntax) 